# Windows 10 Boot Camp USB boots but throws 0xc0000225 before being able to install anything

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, dual-boot, efi

- I have a MBP 2014 15" with all the latest updates installed
- I downloaded the official Windows 10 ISO 64bit (20 november 2019 update)
- I verified that this ISO works, using Virtualbox
- I got a new Kingston 16GB USB stick
- After a few tries I managed to get Boot Camp Assistant (BCA) to

  - install the ISO on the USB
  - copy over the windows support files
  - and make a partition
- BCA chooses to format the USB to exFAT and the partition to NTFS
- **It restarts, boots the USB using EFI and it show the windows logo for a while. Then it crashes with a 0xc0000225 error code**

I've tried the process a few times, because sometimes it failed and the USB got ejected. Maybe the USB is broken? I've also tried manually formatting the drive and copying over the ISO / Windows support files manually. The resulting USB also booted, but with the same error code.

Worth to note is that my macbook might not be a standard 2014 anymore, since I replaced the battery and with that they replaced many other components (like the trackpad / keyboard).

Who can help me on a path towards solving this?

Comment: I does not appear you made any mistakes. If the Boot Camp Assistant created a partition on the internal drive for Windows and you think the flash drive is bad, then you try booting the installation files from this partition as a test.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply! I saw a lot of your other comments too. My Boot Camp Assistant didn't create a partition with installation files.. I think that only happens for Macbook 2015+ that doesn't require the flash drive. Or do you mean I should make an extra 16GB exFAT partition myself and use that instead of the flash drive? Would that be bootable?

Comment: nvm, i assume you mean: just copy over the ISO to the NTFS BOOTCAMP partition and see if it boots. Just to narrow it down.

Comment: I suppose I would use the Disk  Utility to ExFAT format the partition. Mount the ISO and copy the files to the ExFAT volume. Use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software. Copy these files to the ExFAT volume. Check to see if the root folder has the same files as the flash drive. Once finished, try to boot from the ExFAT formatted volume.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked. I got to the installer and past the language screen of the installer, but then I got an error that read something like 'could not read unattend file'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the (new) USB stick was broken from the start. Bought one at a more trustworthy store and it worked out of te box.